# issues with input length and buttonclicks

Tags: function, validation, button, input, flutter

I'm working on a simple math-app for my daughter. Below is some code that you can use if you like (it may not be the most beautiful code, but it works ok and maybe it helps someone).

My issues are:

1) To limit the number of characters (numbers) that the user can type. I only find solutions about this when it comes to textFields (such as maxLength).

2) My refresh-button ("NEXT") is not working at all. The idea is to give the user a new random math-task from the previous arithmetic choice.

3) Currently you can type the wrong answer, click ok and then correct your answer to get a "Correct". The plan is that once you've clicked ok, you won't be able to change your answer. You will only be able to click NEXT. (I plan to implement a counter to this later, that will return the number of correct and false answers after x numbers of tasks).

Any help is highly appreciated (code or what I shall look at). Thank you.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) => runApp(HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'input',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.purple),
      home: FirstClass(),
    );
  }
}

 class FirstClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstClassState createState() => _FirstClassState();
}

class _FirstClassState extends State<FirstClass> {
  final random = Random();
  int a, b, c, sum;
  String output;

  void changeData(String buttonName) {
    setState(() {
      a = random.nextInt(10);
      b = random.nextInt(10);

      if (buttonName == '+') {
         sum = a + b;
        output = '$a+$b= ';
      } else if (buttonName == '-') {
        if (a >= b) {
          sum = a - b;
          output = '$a-$b= ';
        } else if (b > a) {
          sum = b - a;
          output = '$b-$a= ';
        }
      }

      print(sum.toString());
      Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'));
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SecondClass(
                sum: sum,
                refresh: changeData,
                output: output,
                buttonName: buttonName,
              )));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          title: Text(
            'MATH',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('+', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0)),
                  onPressed: () => changeData('+')),
              RaisedButton(
                   child: Text('-', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0)),
                  onPressed: () => changeData('-')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final int sum;
  final String output;
  final String buttonName;
  final Function refresh;

  SecondClass({this.sum, this.refresh, this.buttonName, this.output});

  @override
  _SecondClassState createState() => _SecondClassState();
}

class _SecondClassState extends State<SecondClass> {
  String output = "";
  String _output = "";
  String output2 = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  buttonPressed(String buttonText) {
    if (buttonText == "<-") {
      _output = "";
    } else if (buttonText == "OK") {
      if (output.isNotEmpty) {
        if (output == widget.sum.toString()) {
          setState(() {
            output2 = 'Correct';
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            output2 = 'False';
          });
        }
      } else if (buttonText == "NEXT") {
        widget.refresh(widget.buttonName);
      }
    } else {
      _output = _output + buttonText;
    }
    setState(() {
      output = _output;
    });
    print(buttonText);
  }

  Widget buildButton(String buttonText) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
        child: OutlineButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Text(
              buttonText,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            onPressed: () => buttonPressed(buttonText)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.purple),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 20.0, right: 
20.0),
            child: Container(
                height: 60.0,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    widget.output + output,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 48.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                )),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, right: 
20.0),
            child: Container(
               height: 60.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
              child: Text(
                output2,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 48.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(child: Divider()),
           Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildButton('1'),
                  buildButton('2'),
                  buildButton('3'),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildButton('4'),
                  buildButton('5'),
                  buildButton('6'),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildButton('7'),
                  buildButton('8'),
                  buildButton('9'),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildButton('<-'),
                  buildButton('0'),
                  buildButton('OK'),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildButton('NEXT'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
           ),
        ],
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well It's working. It's not the best way to do this but I tried keep your old code base.I really advise make use of some patterns like BLoC to manage the state of the widgets and avoid setState calls.

Was needed split your code in some more classes.
What I have done here??

- Create a enum called `MathOperation`. This enum is used to identify what kind of arithmetic operation the user selected.
- The older FirstClass is now `OperationSelectorScreen`
- The older SecondClass is now `QuestionAndAnswerScreen`
- I've created `CustomTextField` class to implement a simple 'text field' with a max number of characters.
- I've implmented `MathOperationTask` class. This class is an abstraction for arithmetics operations like sum and subtraction. This class holds the numbers involved in operation, his symbol "+" or "-" and the operation results.

There is some comments in source code to guide you, if you need to ask for something feel free to do I will answer when I can. I hope it helps.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

/// enum used to identify math operation types
enum MathOperation { SUM, SUBTRACTION }

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) => runApp(HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'input',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.purple),
      home: OperationSelectorScreen(),
    );
  }
}

/// old FirstClass
class OperationSelectorScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OperationSelectorScreenState createState() => _OperationSelectorScreenState();
}

class _OperationSelectorScreenState extends State<OperationSelectorScreen> {

  MathOperation _userSelectedOperation;

  void changeData(String buttonName) {
    setState(() {
      if (buttonName == '+') {
        _userSelectedOperation = MathOperation.SUM;
      } else if (buttonName == '-') {
        _userSelectedOperation = MathOperation.SUBTRACTION;
      }

      Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'));

      /// we only need pass to next screen what kind of operation
      /// was selected by user
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => QuestionAndAnswerScreen(
            operationType: _userSelectedOperation,// operation selected by user  ( '+' or '-' )
          )));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          title: Text(
            'MATH',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[

              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('+', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0)),
                  onPressed: () => changeData('+')),

              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('-', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0)),
                  onPressed: () => changeData('-')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// old SecondClass
class QuestionAndAnswerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final operationType; // if the operations will be (+) or (-)

  QuestionAndAnswerScreen({this.operationType});

  @override
  _QuestionAndAnswerScreenState createState() => _QuestionAndAnswerScreenState();
}

class _QuestionAndAnswerScreenState extends State<QuestionAndAnswerScreen> {

  String _userTypedAnswer=""; // numbers that user had typed
  String _answerValidationOutput = ""; // will say if the user answer ir correct or wrong(false)
  MathOperationTask _currentTask; // current arithmetic operation

  // this member controls the back button "<-" activity
  // if user had responded the question, this value will be true and
  // the button "<-" will not work properly.
  bool _isQuestionResponded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //using math operation task generator method to create a new math operation
    _currentTask = MathOperationTask.generateMathTask( widget.operationType );
  }

  buttonPressed(String buttonText) {
    // this logic can be improved if we
    // transform the custom keyboard in a widget

    if (buttonText == "<-") {
      if (!_isQuestionResponded){
        _changeUserTypedText("");
        _changeAnswerValidationText("");
      }
    }

    else if (buttonText == "OK") {
      if (_userTypedAnswer.isNotEmpty) {
        _isQuestionResponded = true;
        if (_userTypedAnswer == _currentTask.results.toString()) {
          _changeAnswerValidationText('Correct');
        }

        else {
          _changeAnswerValidationText('False');
        }
      }
    }

    else if (buttonText == "NEXT") {
      print("new OP");
      _spawnArithmeticOperation();
    }

    else {
      ///This if statement solves the problem of put in member after question
     ///responded.If question is NOT responded, OK button not pressed then we update the text. 
     if (!_isQuestionResponded)
        _changeUserTypedText( (_userTypedAnswer + buttonText) );
    }

  }

  /// this mehtod creates a new arithmetic operation and update the screen with
  void _spawnArithmeticOperation(){
    _currentTask = MathOperationTask.generateMathTask(widget.operationType);
    _answerValidationOutput ="";
    _userTypedAnswer = "";
    _isQuestionResponded = false;
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// method to change and update UI after user type something.
  void _changeUserTypedText(String text){
    setState(() => _userTypedAnswer = text );
  }

  /// update the text if the answer is correct, wrong or clean the text.
  void _changeAnswerValidationText(String text){
    setState(() => _answerValidationOutput = text );
  }

  Widget buildButton(String buttonText) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
        child: OutlineButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Text(
              buttonText,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            onPressed: () => buttonPressed(buttonText)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final operationField = CustomTextField( maxLength: 7, // max text length
      text: "${_currentTask.firstMember}" // first member of operation
          "${_currentTask.operationSymbol}" // operation signal
          "${_currentTask.secondMember}= " // second member of math operation
          "$_userTypedAnswer",
    );

    final answerFinalResultsField = CustomTextField(
        maxLength: 7,
        text: _answerValidationOutput
    );

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.purple),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          operationField,
          answerFinalResultsField,
          Expanded(child: Divider()),
          _buildKeyboard(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // here i put your keyboard layout..
  Widget _buildKeyboard(){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildButton('1'),
            buildButton('2'),
            buildButton('3'),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildButton('4'),
            buildButton('5'),
            buildButton('6'),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildButton('7'),
            buildButton('8'),
            buildButton('9'),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildButton('<-'),
            buildButton('0'),
            buildButton('OK'),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildButton('NEXT'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

/// this class represents an arithmetic operation
/// example 3 + 6 = 9
/// 3 is the firstMember, 6 the secondMember and results is 9.
class MathOperationTask {
  final firstMember;
  final secondMember;
  final results; //operation results
  final operationSymbol;

  // text math symbols constants only to show...
  static final String PLUS = "+";
  static final String LESS = "-";

  MathOperationTask( {this.firstMember, this.secondMember, this.results, this.operationSymbol} );

  /// this method is used to generate a specific math task from a specific type.
  static MathOperationTask generateMathTask( MathOperation type ){
    var random = Random();
    var firstMember = random.nextInt(10);// 0..9
    var secondMember = random.nextInt(10);

    switch(type){
      case MathOperation.SUM:
        return MathOperationTask(
          firstMember: firstMember,
          secondMember: secondMember,
          results: (firstMember + secondMember),
          operationSymbol: PLUS
        );

      case MathOperation.SUBTRACTION:
        var results;

        if (firstMember < secondMember) {
          // we exchange the values position in operation...
          var temp = firstMember;
          firstMember = secondMember;
          secondMember = temp;
        }

        results = firstMember - secondMember;

        return MathOperationTask(
          results: results,
          secondMember: secondMember,
          firstMember: firstMember,
          operationSymbol: LESS,
        );

      default:
        break;
    }

    //in case of invalid operation...
    return MathOperationTask(
      firstMember: 0,
      secondMember: 0,
      results: 0,
    );
  }
}

/// A simple custom text field that limits his text
/// with a specific characters number
///
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final maxLength;
  final _text;

  CustomTextField({this.maxLength = 7, String text}) :
      _text = (text.length > maxLength) ? text.substring(0, maxLength ) : text;
      /// this lines solves characters numbers problem
      ///if the text contains more characters that is allowed (maxLength) then we
      /// cut the string form character 0 until last position allowed (maxLength).

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 60.0,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            _text,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 48.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Awsome answer! Now I know what I shall look deeper into. You can still put in numbers after having pressed "OK". Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: It's possible with a simple if statement. I've update the answer check it out. There is a comment in source code.

Comment: As easy as that :) Thank you very much. Answer is checked and usefull.